# ¿existe una manera en php de verificar si existe un archivo y si existe crear otro con un nombre distinto?

Tags: php7

tengo este siguiente script y mas o menos cumple con lo que quiero osea me crea un archivo llamado archivo1.txt y luego de llenar otra vez el formulario me crea archivo2.txt pero luego no crea el 3,4,5,etc. también trate de agregar un for dentro del if pero generé un bucle infinito

```
<?php
$numero=1;
$numero=strval($numero);
$archiviten="archivo".$numero . ".txt";
$ar = fopen($archiviten,"a") or die ("Error al crear");
$variable1=$_REQUEST['entrada1'];
$variable2=$_REQUEST['entrada2'];
fwrite($ar,$variable1);
fwrite($ar,"\n");
fwrite($ar,$variable2);
echo"se creo correctamente el archivo".$numero;
if (file_exists ("archivo".$numero . ".txt")) {
  $numero = intval($numero);
  $numero=$numero+1;
  $numero=strval($numero);
  $archiviten="archivo".$numero . ".txt";
  $ar = fopen($archiviten,"a") or die ("Error al crear");
  $variable1=$_REQUEST['entrada1'];
  $variable2=$_REQUEST['entrada2'];
  fwrite($ar,$variable1);
  fwrite($ar,"\n");
  fwrite($ar,$variable2);
  echo"se creo correctamente el archivo".$numero;
  // code...
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
// creamos una funcion que recibe el nombre de archivo
function getFileName($filename,$ext){
    // contador
    $contador=1;
    // creamos un while
    while(true){
        // configuramos el nombre
        $current = $filename.$contador .$ext;
        // validamos que no exista
        if(!file_exists($current)){
            // retornamos el nombre
            return $current;
        }
        // sumamos en uno el contador
         $contador++;
    }
}

$newName=getFileName("archivo",".txt");
```

Comment: Hola. Necesitas guardar el contador en alguna parte. Usos sucesivos del método harían que el while sea cada vez más costoso. Otra opción (sugiero) una variable estática $contador, que se inicie con el recuento de archivos presentes en el directorio. Igual garantiza unicidad pero baja ligeramente la cantidad de iteraciones.